# How to get Puma port inside Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, puma

I have some bash script `start_dummy`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#killall puma
ulimit -s 16384
ofile=logs/access_`date +%F_%H%M%S`.log
RACK_ENV=production puma -b tcp://0.0.0.0:22522 2>&1 | tee $ofile
```

and `start_test`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#killall puma
ulimit -s 16384
ofile=logs/access_`date +%F_%H%M%S`.log
RACK_ENV=production puma -b tcp://0.0.0.0:22577 2>&1 | tee $ofile
```

I want to connect different database when the app running on different port:

```
require 'sinatra'
# *snip* sinatra configuration

require 'data_mapper'
DataMapper::Model.raise_on_save_failure = true
if # __WHAT__ # when puma listen on 22577
  DataMapper.setup(:default, 'postgres://original@127.0.0.1/original')
else       # when puma listen on 22522
  DataMapper.setup(:default, 'postgres://dummy@127.0.0.1/dummy')
end
```

what should I insert on `__WHAT__` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if request.port == 22577
    DataMapper.setup(:default, 'postgres://original@127.0.0.1/original')
else
    DataMapper.setup(:default, 'postgres://dummy@127.0.0.1/dummy')
end
```

A better way to do this would be to store the connection string in an environment variable that can be different per server:

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
```